# dynamic resizing with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've seen another reference to this but I can't understand the response.
I am trying to change the height of a page element (#maincontent) dynamically as the window is re-sized.

This is my code:

```
$(function() {
   if($(window).resize()){
      var h1 = $(window).height();
      var h2 = $('#maincontent').height();
      if (h2<h1){
          $('#maincontent').css('height',h1);
      }
   }
});
```

It doesn't work without a page refresh and I can't understand why not. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Or you could use percentages and media queries in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not capturing the window resize event properly:

```
   $(window).resize(function () {

      var h1 = $(window).height();
      var h2 = $('#maincontent').height();
      if (h2<h1){
          $('#maincontent').css('height',h1);
      }

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

The resize function doesn't work like this. It takes a function as argument :

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
       // do things when the window is resized
    });
});
```

Most jquery functions take like this a callback that is called when the event (here 'resize') is sent.

Answer (score 1):

This is because window.resize() takes a function as its argument

EX.

```
    $(function () {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            // your code here
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(e){

        var h1 = $(window).height();
        var h2 = $('#maincontent').height();
        if (h2<h1){
        $('#maincontent').css('height',h1);
        }

    })
 });
```

you should not check if but pass function for resize event

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helpful advice which works perfectly. Now I understand resize() better. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

It's because on page load no `resize` will trigger.

```
var h2 = $('#maincontent').height();

function setSize(){         // wrap you necessary code inside a function
   var h1 = $(window).height();       
   if (h2<h1){
      $('#maincontent').css({height: h1 });
   }
}
setSize();                 // call at page load

$(window).resize(function(){
  setSize();               // and on window resize.
});
```